# How to export bitcoinj wallet

Tags: bitcoinj, private-key-export

I am working on an app which uses bitcoinj. I want to implement export/import functionality to a standard format which can be shared with as many as possible wallet apps.
Is there a standard format used by wallet apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well exporting the raw keys is as standard as you'll get. Different wallet implement their own file format for storing information such as addresses, and keys. But most wallet have at least an "import private key" functionality so that would work.